# How to type object with attributes within list

Tags: typescript

We have some entities in our app. Each entity as a specific type. For example we have:

```
export class Tree {
  constructor(public size: number, public name: string) {}
}

export class Animal {
  constructor(public region: string, public name: string) {}
}
```

We are creating a global search for our app so we can search for any entity.

Our backend returns a list with following example:

```
{
  total: 3,
  Tree: [{ some tree data here }],
  Animal: [{ some animal data here}]
}
```

I want to type this result object in typescript in our frontend and I struggle to get it working: how to indicate my `SearchResult` can have a unknown number of "entities types" containing each an array of these entities?

I tried defining a type which list all possible entities:

```
export type Entities = 'Tree' | 'Animal';
```

then try to use it as key for a new type:

```
export type SearchResults = {
  total: number;
  [K in Entities]: any[];
}
```

But it triggers errors like:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
```

And I cannot use `K` to recover my `Tree[]` and `Animal[]` classes values instead of `any[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your approach, but with definition of `type SearchResults`. You cannot add additional members to mapped type definition. So to correct errors use intersection

```
export type SearchResults = {
  [K in Entities]: any[];
} &
{ total: number; }
```

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). Scroll down and you'll see exact answer